# Converting a patch image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning

I have a code which finds the single patch from the given center coordinate of the image. I want to convert it, so with that it shall find the multiple patches of size 32X32 and stride of 16. The patches should be from the image, neither from border or from the background of it.

```
centerCoord = [70,125];
patchSize = 32;
patchSourceImage = im(centerCoord(1)-ceil(patchSize/2):centerCoord(1)+ceil(patchSize/2)-1,centerCoord(2)-ceil(patchSize/2):centerCoord(2)+ceil(patchSize/2)-1);
```

Comment: Convert your `centerCoord` into a Matrix that stores the center of each patch. Then apply your code to each patch and store it (since each patch has the same size you can store the patches in a (32 x 32 x Npatches) matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Your line of code is large and even if it works I'd recommend make the code easier, so you will be able to check if some regions of the patch (let's call it Regio Of Interest ROI) falls outside the image

Example:

```
im = rand(150, 150);    % 150x150 random "image"
[nrows, ncols] = size(im);

% center coordinates of 4 Patches
centerCoord = [50,50; 100,50; 50,100; 100,100];
patchSize = 32;

% results will be stored in matrix Patches
Patches = zeros(patchSize, patchSize, size(centerCoord,1));

for i=1:size(centerCoord,1)
    top_left = ceil(centerCoord(i,:) - [patchSize/2, patchSize/2]);
    bottom_right = top_left + [patchSize-1, patchSize-1];

    if any(top_left <= 0) || any((bottom_right - [nrows, ncols]) > 0)
        %some regions of the patch fall outside the image. Handle this case here.
    else
        Patches(:,:,i) = im(top_left(1):bottom_right(1), top_left(2):bottom_right(2));
    end
end
```

Here Patches is a 32x32x4 matrix containing your 4 patches.

Comment: i am trying something similar but it only runs for iteration and then it show error of index exceeds the matrix dimesnions.  Can you put the code with loop .

Comment: Thanks but for me the number of patches isn't defined from the beginning. I just know the center of my image say [75 125] and then dynamically i have iterate through all the image and create patches of 32*32 of the whole image by updating the center. The stride with which i can move is 16.

Comment: then just do a loop for `x=1:16:ncols` another loop for `y=1:16:nrows` nd use [x y] as the center of your patches. Some of them will not entirely fall inside the image and will activate the `if` clause in my code. Discard this partches or handle them as needed.

Comment: What you want to do is called "sliding window" and usually is better to use the top-left corner as reference instead of the center of the patch.

Comment: Adding my code to answers ... it gets out of bound after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
im = imread('image98.jpeg');   
 % 150x150 random "image"
 [nrows, ncols] = size(im);

 % center coordinates of 4 Patches
 centerCoord = [75 125];
 patchSize = 32;

 % results will be stored in matrix Patches

 for r=1:16:nrows
     for c =1:16:ncols
     top_left = ceil(centerCoord(1) - [patchSize/2, patchSize/2]);
     bottom_right = top_left + [patchSize-1, patchSize-1];

     if any(top_left <= 0) || any((bottom_right - [nrows, ncols]) > 0)
         fprint('Outside');
     else
        patch = im(centerCoord(1)-ceil(patchSize/2):centerCoord(1)+ceil(patchSize/2)-1,centerCoord(2)- ceil(patchSize/2):centerCoord(2)+ceil(patchSize/2)-1);
         imshow(patch)
         centerCoord(2) =centerCoord(2)+16;
     end
      centerCoord(1) =centerCoord(1)+16
     end
 end
```

Comment: if your image has more than one channel use `[nrows, ncols, nchannels] = size(im);`   Also you are using the for loops but then updating the `centerCoord` without any sense. You update one coord inside the else and the other outside, but both inside the inner loop? Also use the loop variables. And do proper identation of your code.

Comment: how should i update my center coordinates? They needed to be changed after every iteration.

Comment: Which is not what you do. the two coordinates are updated inside the inner loop. Also, you want to start in the center of the image and move right and down? What about the top left part of the image?

Comment: I am confused ..can you show write that part of a code on how should i update my cooordinate.

Comment: You are not even using my code. your patch is using the centerCoordinate instead of the TopLeft and BottomRight. Redo all your code, forget about centerCoordinate and center of the image. Just do a sliding window over all the image with a step of 16.  The author of the question and you are doing the same School exercice?

Comment: But since you are not even updating the coordinates at the right place or properly identing your code, I would recommend first reading a little bit how to use loops and access matrices in matlab. Once this is clear you can try to develop more complex things but you need first some kind of basic knowledge